# Group layout, bug/weird behaviour when using manual gaps

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, grouplayout

I'm experiencing some Issues with `GroupLayout`.
When disabling elements at runtime, manual gaping seems to be broken.
There is a huge gap between elements that simply isn't there when using automatic gaps.

**Automatic gaps:**

labels enabled:

[image]


labels 1-8 disabled:

[image]


**Manual gaps:**


labels enabled:

[image]


labels 1-8 disabled:

[image]

Is it a bug, or have I forgot some settings ?

Here the according code:

```
public class GroupLayoutTesting extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GroupLayoutTesting();
}

public GroupLayoutTesting() {
    super();

    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(600,100));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.getContentPane().add(getGroupLayouted());
}

static JLabel[] labels = {
    new JLabel("Label 0"),
    new JLabel("Label 1"),
    new JLabel("Label 2"),
    new JLabel("Label 3"),
    new JLabel("Label 4"),
    new JLabel("Label 5"),
    new JLabel("Label 6"),
    new JLabel("Label 7"),
    new JLabel("Label 8"),
    new JLabel("Label 9")
};

private Component getGroupLayouted() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
    //layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true); // <- automatic gaps
    panel.setLayout(layout);

    JButton btn = new JButton("Light switch");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i = 1; i<9; i++){
                labels[i].setVisible(!labels[i].isVisible());
            }
        }
    });

    SequentialGroup sequentialGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(sequentialGroup);
    sequentialGroup.addComponent(btn);
    sequentialGroup.addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED,10,10); //<- Manual gaps

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        sequentialGroup.addComponent(labels[i]);
        sequentialGroup.addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED,10,10); //<- Manual gaps
    }

    ParallelGroup parallelGroup = layout.createParallelGroup();
    layout.setVerticalGroup(parallelGroup);
    parallelGroup.addComponent(btn);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        parallelGroup.addComponent(labels[i]);
    }

    return panel;
 }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Please state your problem with my question a bit more specific. I do not really get whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing untoward. The gaps are a guide to *distributing* components within a container. Without a specific reason, I'd stick with the automatic gaps, since "they automatically [adjust](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) to the look and feel the UI runs with, reflecting the actual look and feel guidelines."

For reference, I've updated your example as shown below. Empirically, a manual `GAP` of `0` matches the automatic gaps on my platform, but not the container gaps. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.ParallelGroup;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.SequentialGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

public class GroupLayoutTesting extends JFrame {

    private static final int GAP = 0;

    public GroupLayoutTesting() {
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(getGroupLayouted());
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    static JLabel[] labels = {
        new JLabel("Label-0"),
        new JLabel("Label-1"),
        new JLabel("Label-2"),
        new JLabel("Label-3"),
        new JLabel("Label-4"),
        new JLabel("Label-5"),
        new JLabel("Label-6"),
        new JLabel("Label-7"),
        new JLabel("Label-8"),
        new JLabel("Label-9")
    };

    private JPanel getGroupLayouted() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Light switch");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 1; i < labels.length - 1; i++) {
                    labels[i].setVisible(!labels[i].isVisible());
                }
            }
        });

        SequentialGroup sequentialGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(sequentialGroup);
        sequentialGroup.addComponent(btn);
        //sequentialGroup.addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED, GAP, GAP); //<- Manual gaps

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sequentialGroup.addComponent(labels[i]);
            //sequentialGroup.addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED, GAP, GAP); //<- Manual gaps
        }

        ParallelGroup parallelGroup = layout.createParallelGroup();
        layout.setVerticalGroup(parallelGroup);
        parallelGroup.addComponent(btn);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            parallelGroup.addComponent(labels[i]);
        }
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new GroupLayoutTesting();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sticking with automatic gaps is simply not an option for me. To be honest I am pretty disappointed that it is apparently not possible to reproduce that (really useful) behavior.

Comment: You may want to consider a [custom layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html).

Comment: As this is the only Issue I have experienced with the GroupLayout, I'll try to avoid this type of solution. I think I will try to assign gaps to the corresponding components first and deactivate them when their parent components are made invisible.

Answer (score 1):

`GroupLayout` manager has the `setHonorsVisibility()` method that
decides whether component visibility is considered when sizing and
positioning components. The default value is true which means
that the size of the hidden components does not place a role in 
layout calculations.

However, the gaps remain. So the distance between the label 0 
and label 9 is the sum of the nine gaps. The gaps are layout
objects too and they are not affected by hiding components.

My assumtion is that the `setAutoCreateGaps()` is called at
the end of the layout process (hiding a component initiates 
a new layout process) and it inserts gaps between
existing visible components (if `honorsVisibility` is true). This is
why your second example has only one gap set between the
remaining labels.

With `honorsVisibility` set to false, the visibility of
components is not honored; in other words the size of the
labels is taken into account despite the fact that they
are hidden.

The following example shows sets the `honorsVisibility`
to false:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.ParallelGroup;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.SequentialGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

public class GroupLayoutTesting extends JFrame {

    private final JLabel[] labels = {
        new JLabel("Label 0"),
        new JLabel("Label 1"),
        new JLabel("Label 2"),
        new JLabel("Label 3"),
        new JLabel("Label 4"),
        new JLabel("Label 5"),
        new JLabel("Label 6"),
        new JLabel("Label 7"),
        new JLabel("Label 8"),
        new JLabel("Label 9")
    };

    public GroupLayoutTesting() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Labels");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);

        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);        

        JButton btn = new JButton("Light switch");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
                    labels[i].setVisible(!labels[i].isVisible());
                }
            }
        });

        gl.setHonorsVisibility(false);

        SequentialGroup seqGroup = gl.createSequentialGroup();
        gl.setHorizontalGroup(seqGroup);
        seqGroup.addComponent(btn);
        //seqGroup.addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED, 10, 10); //<- Manual gaps

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            seqGroup.addComponent(labels[i]);
           // seqGroup.addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED, 10, 10); //<- Manual gaps
        }

        ParallelGroup parGroup = gl.createParallelGroup();
        gl.setVerticalGroup(parGroup);
        parGroup.addComponent(btn);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            parGroup.addComponent(labels[i]);
        }

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GroupLayoutTesting ex = new GroupLayoutTesting();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The screenshot shows that the two labels remain in their initial positions.

[image: Labels]

Comment: You got my upvote for a possible explanation :) But still not a solution.